# Setting global default laravel parameters?

Tags: laravel-6.2

I call this for many of my views:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('dashboard' , array(
      'companyName' => 'Yoyo.Yo',
      'showSlideMenu' => true,
      'showTopNavigation' => true,
      'showExpanded' => true,
      'userTasks' => COMMON_getUserTasks(),
      'userCash' => COMMON_getUserCash(),
    ));
}
```

I would love for my views to "automatically" know that, for example, "companyName" is always "Yoyo.yo", without having to set it like above for each view.

Is there a way to globally set defaults for these values?

**CONTEXT**

I set up the default email verifications routes:

- email/verify
- email/resend

Using:

```
Auth::routes();
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

in web.php

I can easily edit the template, but I don't know how to make these routes that are being created, aware of the variables that I need on each view.

(Also, its cumbersome to have to specify it for each view when the defaults are usually the same)

**HACK**

I know I can do something like the template:

```
<?php
   $companyName = isset($companyName) ? $companyName : 'My Default';
?>
```

But that seems too hacky. Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to allow easy customisation of this "constants", you can create a custom config file for it (or append to any existing):

`config/defaults.php`:

```
<?php
    return [
        "company_name" => "Acme Inc."
    ];
```

Then you can use the config facade directly on your views:

`resources/views/your-view.blade.php`:

```
<p>Welcome to {{ config("defaults.company_name") }}</p>
```

Additionally you can use environment variables, so you don't need to change any code, just your `.env` file:

`config/defaults.php`:

```
<?php
    return [
        "company_name" => env("DEFAULT_COMPANY_NAME", "Acme Inc.")
    ];
```

`.env`:

```
DEFAULT_COMPANY_NAME=My Company
```

If `DEFAULT_COMPANY_NAME` is not set on `.env`, it will fallback to "Acme Inc."

Comment: This certainly helps with the more generic ones like Company Name. But would still like to have defaults for certain variables, and then override them in each controller IF i want to.